# MutableLivedata observer triggering

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, mutablelivedata

I have a question about `MutableLiveData` in `Viewmodel`. Does just `setValue` function of `MutableLiveData` trigger observation? If we change content of `MutableLiveData` witout `setValue`, may it be triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it. Only the mothods below dispatch events to observables:

```
liveData.postValue("a");
liveData.setValue("b");
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MutableLiveData

Answer (score 1):

It will only trigger if you call `setValue` or `postValue`. If you use Kotlin then you can write yourself an extension to trigger the `LiveData`:

```
fun <T> MutableLiveData<T>.trigger() {
    value = value
}
```

and then you can simply call:

```
mutableLiveData.trigger()
```

Comment: This was a cute one... ...`trigger` should have been a standard member.

Answer (score 0):

Both `setValue()` & `postValue` will trigger the events. The only difference is, `postValue()` can trigger the observation event from background thread as well. Whereas, `setValue` must be called within main thread. 
`postValue()` is preferred to `setValue()`.